# Direct sum of graded modules are a graded module

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

if $M=\bigoplus M_d$ and $N=\bigoplus N_d$ are two graded $R$-modules ($R$ is a graded ring) then $M\oplus N$ is a graded module.

I try to write $M\oplus N= \left ( \bigoplus_{d} M_d \right ) \oplus \left (\bigoplus_{d'} N_{d'} \right )=\bigoplus_{d,d'}(M_d\bigoplus N_{d'})$ but i can't fully understand how to prove that it is a graded module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M = \bigoplus_d M_d$ and $N = \bigoplus_d N_d$ are graded modules, then their direct sum is graded as

$$\left ( M \oplus N \right )_d = M_d \oplus N_d$$

That is, we decompose

$$M \oplus N = \bigoplus_d M_d \oplus N_d$$

To see that this really is a grading, notice

$$(m_d + n_d) + (m_{d'} + n_{d'}) = (m_d + m_{d'}) + (n_d + n_{d'})$$

so addition in $M \oplus N$ respects the grading because addition in $M$ and $N$ do.

Similarly, if $r \in R_{d'}$, then

$$
r(m_d + n_d) = r m_d + r n_d
$$

so scalar multiplication respects the grading in $M \oplus N$ because it does in $M$ and $N$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yes, this help me a loot to understand

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, you should mark it as such by clicking the checkmark next to it. This way other users on the site know how to spend their time ^_^